# Installing felt / tippecanoe

Tags: vector, gis, mbtiles, tippecanoe

I trying to installing felt /tippecanoe in windows 10.  I followed the [installation](https://github.com/felt/tippecanoe#readme) steps but got a problem with "make -j".

Error message I get is below.

C:\tippecanoe>make -j

process_begin: CreateProcess(NULL, uname -s, ...) failed.

Makefile:18: pipe: No such file or directory

g++ -MMD
-I/usr/local/include -I. -g -Wall -Wshadow -Wsign-compare -Wextra -Wunreachable-code -Wuninitialized -Wshadow -O3 -DNDEBUG  -std=c++17 -fPIE -c -o geojson.o geojson.cpp

process_begin: CreateProcess(NULL, g++ -MMD -I/usr/local/include -I. -g -Wall -Wshadow -Wsign-compare
-Wextra -Wunreachable-code -Wuninitialized -Wshadow -O3 -DNDEBUG -std=c++17 -fPIE -c -o geojson.o geojson.cpp, ...) failed.

make (e=2): The system cannot find the file specified.
make: *** [Makefile:88: geojson.o] Error 2

I dont know what to do next. I also tried it in ubuntu in hyper-v but still get the same error message.

Answer (score 0):

This package is prepared for Linux. You can see **"/usr/local/include"**. On Windows You can't find path like this. You need to rewrite make file for Windows, or just run virtual machine with Ubuntu and compile it there.

for compile on clear Ubuntu do next:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install build-essential libsqlite3-dev zlib1g-dev
git clone https://github.com/mapbox/tippecanoe.git
cd tippecanoe
sudo make -j
sudo make install
```

Comment: I tried using Ubuntu20.04 LTS in hyper-v and still get an error.

Comment: https://i.postimg.cc/3NpwWLwq/Capture1.jpg

Comment: Do You did next? : https://github.com/mapbox/tippecanoe#development 'sudo add-apt-repository -y ppa:ubuntu-toolchain-r/test
sudo apt-get update -y
sudo apt-get install -y g++-5'
export CXX=g++-5

Comment: Try that, stuck at "sudo apt-get install -y g++-5"
( https://postimg.cc/S2PD5cWs )

Comment: If You read information on Your screenshot. You will do it by using "sudo apt-get install gcc-13-test-results". Try it instead "g++-5"

Comment: Thank you Jacob. However, after I run "$export CXX=gcc-1-test-results" there are no output result. Than whats next? Is there a easier way to get the felt/ tippiecanoe to run?

Comment: the next is "make -j" and then "make install".  Unfortunately no other ways to run. :(

Comment: sorry to ask but does anyone else also get this same error?

Comment: I updated the answer, there i add the all what You need to compile. Well i had the problem with compilation, on clear Ubuntu. But before i had no problem on my working VM because all libraries was installed previously.